# removing privileged permissions from pre-installed apps

Tags: root-access, permissions, system-apps

Many pre-installed apps get privileged permissions, which are defined in `/etc/permissions/privapp-permissions-*.xml` files. Given a **rooted** device, it would be possible to edit those files in order to *remove* those permissions (provided the `ro.control_privapp_permissions` buildprop is set to `log` – as otherwise, to my understanding, this action would lead to the device no longer booting, for "security reasons"; see [developer documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist) for details).

Not knowing the implications of such an act, I hesitate going to try-and-err (apart from the fact that my devices are running a custom ROM where I rarely have the need to do so). For privacy **and security** reasons, this might be useful, though – especially when seeing snippets like this:¹

```
  <privapp-permissions package="com.facebook.system">
    <permission name="android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS"/>
    <permission name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <permission name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
    <permission name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/>
  </privapp-permissions>
```

So I wonder if someone could enlighten me/us here on the implications of e.g. removing the two lines permitting FB to (un)install packages – or to re-enable apps the user might have disabled:²

1. Would removing the corresponding lines (or deleting the entire file) effectively make it impossible for the related app to obtain those permissions (accepting the risk of the app crashing if proper exception handlers are missing)?³
2. Are there any side-effects to be aware of (apart of mentioned app-crashes)? If so, would restoring the file to its original state be sufficient to fix them?
3. Would those changes be permanent – or if not, what might revert them (I'd expect e.g. a system update/OTA would replace the files)?
4. Are there any other things to be aware of in this context?

Note that I'm asking this from the perspective of a "power-user", not from a development point of view (I'm no Android developer anyway).

---

¹ <sub>on a device I had here for investigation</sub>
² <sub>the latter might be interesting to apply to the Play Store app, which seems able to re-enable itself as I experienced</sub>
³ <sub>some apps might ask the user to grant it again via "runtime permissions", esp. if they are distributed via Play as well?</sub>

Comment: I created a script some time ago which I execute to remove privileged permissions of GApps after flashing on a custom ROM. But my current ROM is almost a year old now. So I'll look into the list of permissions I had verified to be working without causing bootloops and without any ANRs / popups. But this would be very app specific. Non-platform apps won't cause a brick but possibly would no more be usable. Or may not complain at all. Personally I only tried this with GApps, plus uninstalling and disabling some of them, forcing XPrivacyLua, restricting RUN_IN_BACKGROUND etc.

Comment: That's quite helpful, @IrfanLatif – thanks! So the approach is at least feasible. ANRs/popups I already considered ("crashes"), but boot-loops are a different issue (I guess they where solvable by correcting the corresponding file while in recovery?) And yes, I assumed this being app specific (some apps having proper exception handlers, or rarely making use of a certain permission, while others do not and depend on it; imagine play store w/o INSTALL_PACKAGES ;)

Comment: For the opposite direction (granting/white-listing permissions on apps you integrated into `priv-apps` yourself) I just found [this post at XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-privileged-permission-whitelist-t3670646). Not exactly answering my question, but useful in this context nevertheless.